# Reactjs array loop not working if the condition fails or in the negative condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to loop the `array` below.

**Conditions**:
If system: TEST ID is "No Number" i want to display "system": "ALT ID" id as "123456789" else I should display system: TEST ID "id"

**Current status**:
This code works fine when TEST ID has value "No Number", but if TEST ID has any number like "2345678" this code is not working.

```js
"FindId": [
    {
        "id": "No Number",
        "system": "TEST ID"
    },
    {
        "id": "123456789",
        "system": "ALT ID"
    }
]

let result = FindId && FindId.find(data => data.system === "TEST ID").id
if (result === "No Number") {
    result = FindId.find(data => data.system === "ALT ID").id
}

return { result }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. If "TEST ID" is "No NUmber" makes no sense as "TEST ID" is a value in your object and not a property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```js
FindId = [
  {
    id: "No Number",
    system: "TEST ID",
  },
  {
    id: "123456789",
    system: "ALT ID",
  },
];

const testId = FindId?.find((data) => data.system === "TEST ID")?.id;
const altId = FindId?.find((data) => data.system === "ALT ID")?.id;
const result = testId === "No Number" ? altId : "id";

console.log(`TEST ID: ${result}`);
```

Comment: I took some idea from your suggested code.  Ternary operator syntax needs to be corrected. Thanks so much for the response